# How to apply adjustments to slices in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have an image splitted into 3 parts by the slice tool.
I also have a couple of adjustments that I want to apply only on the second and the third part of the image.

[image]

What is the way to do this in Photoshop?

Comment: Select and mask each area individually. If you make a marquee selection and then add a layer adjustment, it will covert that into a mask, but if you're planning to add multiple adjustments to each area... I think I would make 3 groups and add layer mask to all of them and stick adjustments inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a slice with the slice selection tool. Copy it to the clipboard with Ctrl+C. Paste in place. You get a new layer which contains the stuff in your slice. You can adjust it and merge back when you are 200% sure the original can be replaced.

Or you can Ctrl+Click it in the layers panel and make a selection which covers the slice. You can use it to edit the original or to create automatically a perfect layer mask when you add an Adjustment layer. Delete the generated slice content layer when it's not needed.

There's also another way to make a selection which is pixel perfectly the same as your slice. Put option View > Snap to slice = ON. Then drag a rectangular selection marquee.  If you carefully start from a slice corner, the selection snaps to the slice border.

Comment: Thanks, the last solution was to quickest.